# Angularjs: How to insert bulk data

Tags: angularjs

Unable to insert bulk data getting error as VM515:1 Uncaught ReferenceError

```
 $scope.SaveBulk = function (User) {
        for (var i = 0; i < User.length; i++) {
            debugger;
            var _user= $scope.User[i];
            console.log(_user);
        }
```

In user getting data in object Like `[Object$$hashKey: "object:3"fname: "a"lname: "w"__proto__: Object, Object]`
when i'm trying to loop it getting error at _user.

Comment: It seems like the **User** is not an array. Make sure it is an array then your code should work.

Comment: Can you show the code from where `SaveBulk` is getting invoked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't create `$scope.User`. Instead you should log `User[i]`. That's the array you are iterating.

```
$scope.SaveBulk = function (User) {
    for (var i = 0; i < User.length; i++) {
        debugger;
        var _user= User[i];
        console.log(_user);
    }
}
```